# Struts2 StreamResult not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, struts2

I'm trying to allow downloading of PDFs located on a file system. I have an action class DownloadFileAction that extends ActionSupport that basically does the following:

```
public String execute() {
  // lookup file
  inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  return SUCCESS;
}

public String getContentType() {
  return "application/pdf";
}

public String getContentDisposition() {
  return "attachment;filename=\"filename.pdf\"";
}
```

My action mapping is defined as you'd expect:

```
<action name="downloadFile" class="com.foo.DownloadFileAction">
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="allowCaching">false</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

This works great in Firefox and IE9, but fails to work in IE8 for unknown reasons.  Any thoughts?

---

**Update**: Using Live HTTP Headers plugin, I see this when doing the download in Firefox. I assume this would be the same in IE8:

```
 http://fmpdmb:7001/shopping/search/printItemDetail.action?upid=41271812&OeT2rTJY=LIJ8HDLqT7igptDozBz5ocIg

 GET /shopping/search/printItemDetail.action?upid=41271812&OeT2rTJY=LIJ8HDLqT7igptDozBz5ocIg
 HTTP/1.1 
 Host: fmpdmb:7001 
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1 
 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 Connection: keep-alive 
 Referer: http://fmpdmb:7001/shopping/search/searchResultItemDetail.action?upid=41271812
 Cookie: ADMINCONSOLESESSION=vQpcPk2N58P1QZtLrPVHyWjvS9pDmT2b60pdrpqHrBHQhjGBLmhV!-1356202776;
 EMALL-SESSION=r7FbPrmCQ1DVQt1Wkf214nznpT61L03JHhN1d7Z8TZzH5tzCXvdm!1350268378

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: no-cache 
 Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 15:48:00 GMT 
 Pragma: nocache, no-cache 
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Content-Type: application/pdf 
 Expires: 0 
 Content-Disposition: inline;filename="document.pdf" 
 X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

---

**Update**: A bit more info.  I think this may have something to do with the fact that the app is running under https.  Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

the action should look like this:

```
<action name="download" class="com.project.DownloadAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
      <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
      <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
      <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="download.pdf"</param>
      <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
   </action>
```

**UPDATE**

check out this article: [Internet Explorer Cannot Download https://something](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx). if you are using https and prevent caching, download would fail.

try define something like this would help you to prevent the error:

```
 Cache-Control: private, max-age=15
```

Comment: I can define those parameters in the action